# ng-click for button is not working on mobile view of datatable

Tags: html, css, angularjs, datatable

Could someone help find why ng-click is not working on mobile view of Datatable?

```
 <tr class="child">
       <td class="child" colspan="3">
          <ul data-dtr-index="0">
             <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
                <span class="dtr-title">
                   <div class="table-header">
                      <span class="column-title ng-binding">Location</span>
                   </div>
                </span>
                <span class="dtr-data">19107</span>
             </li>
             <li data-dtr-index="4" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="4">
                <span class="dtr-title">
                   <div class="table-header">
                      <span class="column-title ng-binding">Status</span>
                   </div>
                </span>
                <span class="dtr-data">
                   <select ng-model="x.ACT_STATUS" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
                      <option value="? object:null ?"></option>
                      <option value="Y">YES</option>
                      <option value="N">NO</option>
                   </select>
                </span>
             </li>
             <li data-dtr-index="5" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="5">
                <span class="dtr-title">
                   <div class="table-header">
                      <span class="column-title ng-binding"></span>
                   </div>
                </span>
                <span class="dtr-data"><button class="md-raised md-accent md-button md-default-theme md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="update('x')"><span class="ng-scope">
                Save
                </span></button></span>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to show more of your code. It is probably that you need [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) for **ng-click** to work with mobile devices. You will then inject it into your module with:

```
angular.module('app',['ngTouch']);
```